# Batch File Not Connecting to Database

Tags: batch-file, sqlanywhere

I am trying to automatically execute a SQL script with a batch file.  Here is what I have in my batch file

```
@echo off

dbisql  -c "Server=servername ;DBN=databasename ;UID=UserID;PWD=password" SqlFile.sql  

pause
```

It says that the server was not found

Comment: Do I have all the parameters I need?  Why is it not working?

Comment: We need more information. Is the server running on the same machine? What command did you use to start the server?

Comment: I think I have a better idea.  Apparently, I can export data from SQL Anywhere using an output to statement.

However, when I tried to put an output to statement in a procedure or an event, I get an error message:



create procedure TestProcedure
as
begin 

SELECT *
FROM test
OUTPUT TO 'C:\\...filename.txt'
FORMAT TEXT

end

Comment: The server is not on the same machine.  I didn't know that I had to issue a command to start the server

Answer (score 0):

If the server is not on the same machine, you have to tell the client that. You can do that in one of two ways:

1. Add the hostname of the machine where the server is running to the connection string, like: `Server=<servername>;...;host=<hostname>`. If the server is not running on the default port (2638), you can add the port number too, using `host=<hostname>:<port>`. This is the preferred method.
2. Add the `links=tcpip` parameter to the connection string. This is an older method and won't work if the server is on a different subnet.